# Azure Cloud Service - different mapping per environment

Tags: azure, configuration, mapping, azure-cloud-services, cscfg

I have a Cloud Service in Azure and I have multiple environments.
One of my classes use a mapping (key-value mapping) for doing some calculations.
The number of keys in that mapping varies depending on the environment.

I'm guessing I have no choice but to insert (somehow) the mapping to the environment's configuration (`.cscfg` file).
Since the configuration is in `XML` format, I'm wondering what would be the cleanest and most extensible way for define the mapping for each of the environments.

Thanks

---

For example:

I have this ID to Region mapper:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Region> Id = new Dictionary<string, Region>
{
    {"1", Region.UsE},
    {"2", Region.UsE},
    {"3", Region.UsE},
    {"4", Region.UsSC},
    {"5", Region.UsSC},
    {"6", Region.UsSC},
    {"7", Region.EuW},
    {"8", Region.EuN}
};
```

This mapping changes between environments and I would like somehow to elegantly set the mapping in the `cscfg` file of each environment.

Hope this better explains my question.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: have you considered environment variables? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common/#define-environment-variables-before-a-role-starts

Answer (score 0):

You can add the values to the [ConfigurationSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156212.aspx) element of the .CSCFG files for each environment. The values may then be read using the [CloudConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt634650.aspx) class.

You could also just have per-environment XML or JSON files.

Comment: But the number of properties in this dictionary varies per environment.

Comment: I think you need to look into ARM templates, in that case.